# Vectorizing addition

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two numpy arrays `a[n,3]` and `b[m,3]`

How do I calculate `c[n,m,3]` , without resorting to a `for` loop, such as:

`c[i,j,:] = a[i,:] + b[j,:]`

Comment: `a[:,None]+b[None,:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
c = a[:, None, :] + b[None, :, :]
```

Comment: Trailing `:` are unnecessary. This is equivalent `a[:, None] + b[None]`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that trailing `:` is not necessary but I like to keep it to make it clearer that `c` is a 3D array just for my understanding.